# Explicit model of the torus is a quotient of $[0,1] \times [0,1]$ mod $R$

Tags: general-topology, quotient-spaces

I have been given the following definition:

Given a equivalence relation $R$ on a set $X$, a quotient of $X$ modulo $R$ is a pair $(Y, \pi$) consisting of a set $Y$ and a surjection $\pi : X \rightarrow Y$ (called the quotient map) with the property that $\pi(x) = \pi(y) \Leftrightarrow (x, y) \in R$.

Now the question is the following:

Describe the equivalence relation $R$ on $[0, 1]\times[0,1]$ that encodes the gluing to construct a torus. Then prove that the explicit model given by

$$T = \bigg\{(x, y, z) \in \mathbb{R}^{3} : \Big(\sqrt{x^2 + y^2} - R\Big)^2 + z^2 = r^2\bigg\}$$

is a quotient of $[0,1]\times[0,1]$ modulo $R$ in the sense of the previous definition (of course you also have to describe the map $\pi$).

So my equivalence relation:

$(x, y)\sim(w, z)\Leftrightarrow (x = 0, w = 1, y = z), (x = 1, w = 0, y = z), (y = 0, z = 1, x = w), (y = 1, z = 0, x = w)$.

I can't solve the rest of the problem. I lack understanding of what $\pi$ exactly is and how to relate $\pi$ to the explicit model for the torus. And what is $Y$ in this case? Some help with these concepts would be much appreciated!

Comment: Your equivalence relation should also make each point in $[0,1]^2$ equivalent to itself, since equivalence relations have to be reflexive.  Also, when working on the second part, change the notation so that the equivalence relation and the bigger radius aren't both denoted by the same letter $R$.

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* Parametrize the torus with two families of orthogonal circles in the natural way. Then  consider $f:[0,1] \times [0,1] \to S_1 \times S_1$ given by $(u,v) \mapsto (\cos 2\pi u, \sin 2\pi u,\cos 2\pi v, \sin 2\pi v)$ and $R$ given by $(u,v) R (u',v') \iff f(u,v) = f(u',v')$. Make sure you see that $R$ identifies opposite sides of the square.

Comment: How do you prove that $f(u,v)=f(u',v')$ then $(u,v) R (u',v')$? Perhaps you can help me in this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4678065/homeomorphism-torus