# Homeomorphism torus

Tags: general-topology, quotient-spaces

Let $X=[0,1]\times [0,1] \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ and consider the following partition of $X$:

1. the set $\{(0,0),(1,0),(0,1),(1,1)\}$
2. sets consisting of pairs of points $(x,0)$, $(x,1)$, where $0 < x < 1$;
3. sets consisting of pairs of points $(0,y)$, $(1,y)$, where $0 < y < 1$;
4. sets consisting of a single point $(x,y)$ with $0<x<1$ and $0<y<1$.

This induces a equivalence relation
$$(x,y) \sim (w,z) \Leftrightarrow (x,y), (w,z) \hbox{ belong to the same type of set of the partition above}.$$

Let $f=[0,1]\times [0,1] \rightarrow S^1\times S^1$ given by
\begin{equation*}
f(x,y)=(e^{2\pi i x}, e^{2 \pi i y}).
\end{equation*}

I already proved that $(x,y) \sim (w,z)$ then $f(x,y)=f(w,z)$.

My question:

> Is it true that $f(x,y)=f(w,z)$ then $(x,y) \sim (w,z)$?

If so, how can we prove this?

Comment: If I understand correctly, then your question boils down to: if $x, w \in [0,1]$ and $e^{2\pi i x} = e^{2\pi i w}$ then either $x = w$ or $\{x, w\} = \{0, 1\}$. But there is very little context/background about this reduced question, in particular: (1) Is it clear to you that your question reduces to this? (2) What do you know about the map $x \mapsto e^{2 \pi i x}$?

Comment: @ronno If you can answer that ($x,w \in [0,1]$ then $x=w$ or $\{x,w\}=\{0,1\}$), it would help me, the rest I can do. The map $x \mapsto e^{2\pi i x}$ can be seen as $x \mapsto (\cos(2\pi i x), \sin(2 \pi i x))$.

Comment: You mean $(\cos(2\pi x), \sin(2\pi x))$. If your definition of $\sin$ and $\cos$ (for real arguments) are in terms of the unit circle then that tells you $2\pi x$ and $2\pi w$ differ by a multiple of $2\pi$, so $x$ and $w$ differ by an integer. Otherwise you should add your definitions.

Comment: @ronno If $x$ and $w$ differ by an integer, how can I conclude that $x=w$ or $\{x,w\}=\{0,1\}$? If $x,\in [0,1]$ then $x-y \in [-1,1]$, which implies that $x-y \in \{-1,0,1\}$. If $x-y=0$ we are done. What about the other cases?

Comment: If $x - y = -1$ and $x > 0$ then $y > 1$, so the only way you can have $x - y = -1$ with $x, y \in [0, 1]$ is if $x = 0$, $y = 1$. Similarly if $x - y = 1$.